# Vertical menu Text-decoration not working

Tags: html, css

Facing problem in Multi Level vertical menu,

```
Text-Decoration:none;
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zu007/407egkuo/)
not working. showing  Unorder list Circle 
How to fix this

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. here we like you to make sure your question is complete, rather than having to click through to other sites. Can you please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and follow the advice  and then we can begin to help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADD this in your code: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/407egkuo/3/)**

```
ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

ul > li a{
      text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `list-style-type: none;`. It will remove your Unorder list Circle.

```
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Hope it will help you.